# An extremely simple classification problem leads to intractable SVM program

Tags: svm

In the popular textbook Mathematics for Machine Learning, creating a SVM requires solving:

$\text{min}_{w,b} \dfrac{1}{2}\|w\|^2$

subject to $y_n (w^T x_n + b) \geq 1$, for all $n = 1, \ldots, N$

---

Ok, then let $(x_n, y_n) = ((1, 0), +1), ((0, -1), -1)$

This is an extremely simple dataset to classify. The classifier is: $\text{sign}(x_{[1]} 
+ x_{[2]})$, where $x_{[i]}$ is the $i$th coordinate of $x$

Yet, the SVM program reduces to,

$\text{min}_{w,b} \dfrac{1}{2}\|w\|^2$

subject to $w_1  + b \geq 1$ and $w_2 - b \geq 1$.

We have two equations but three unknowns. We cannot solve this question. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where you are unclear here. We have two constraints and a minimization - the problem can be easily solved.

Rather than plugging this into a solver I'm just doing it by hand since it's so simple.

Candidate solution $w_1 = w_2 = 1$, $b = 0$. Then $\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 = 1$ and the constraints are satisfied. Noting that $w_1 \geq 1 - b$ and $w_2 \geq 1 + b$, if $||b|| > 1$ then we would have $\textrm{max}(w_1,w_2) > 2$ and $\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 \geq 2$.

So necessarily, $||b|| \leq 1$ and thus $1 \pm b \geq 0$ and $w_1 = 1-b$, $w_2 = 1+b$ at the solution. Plugging this in, we need to minimize $\frac{1}{2}\left[(1-b)^2 + (1+b)^2\right]$ subject to $||b|| \leq 1$. That objective is simply $1 + b^2$ which is minimized when $b=0$, and thus the solution is $w_1 = w_2 = 1, b=0$.

Which gives us exactly the desired classifier.